# Qual a diferença entre os "rands" no PHP?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber o que difere o rand do mt_rand e o  mt_srand; E caso tenha algum outro rand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand.php): Gerador melhorado de números aleatórios

```
<?php
   echo mt_rand() . "\n";
   echo mt_rand() . "\n";
   echo mt_rand(5, 15);
?>
```

[`mt_srand`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-srand.php): Semeia o gerador melhorado de números aleatórios

```
<?php
   // semente de microsegundos
   function make_seed()
   {
      list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
      return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
   }
   mt_srand(make_seed());
   $randval = mt_rand();
?>
```

[`srand`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.srand.php): Semeia o gerador de números aleatórios

```
<?php
   // Semeia com microsegundos
   function make_seed()
   {
      list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
      return $sec + $usec * 1000000;
   }
   srand(make_seed());
   $randval = rand();
?>
```